# Firefox add in to display (and allow me to copy) the fragment id of a section

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Is there a Firefox add-on (or other method) to find out what fragment id such as http://example.com/page#fragment - I would like to be able to bookmark a reference to a large page (or paste into an email/ posting ).

To date I have viewed source and looked for such stuff as below - but it can be fiddly waiding through a big file.

```
<a name="fragment"></a>
<h2 id="fragment">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, using the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) add-on: use Information » Display Anchors (despite its name, and despite a dedicated Display Id & Class Details, this will in fact show ids as well).

There's a dedicated add-on, which I actually find a bit harder to use as it needs a right-click to even just see the anchor's name: [Show Anchors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/show-anchors/). It renders the anchors nicely though:

[image: The show anchors add-on in action]

In Safari and Chrome: right-click, Inspect Element makes the Web Inspector jump to the element of your interest right away. (Likewise in Firefox when you have the Firebug add-on installed.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there are many different ways to write your website, and an AddIn would have to parse to code for all possibilities. Also, an anchor is a position with the document, and does not have an end...at least not a fixed one.

But there's an AddIn called [SiteSlicer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6931) which does something similar to what you requested. Also I can remember an AddIn which a similar functionality tot he WebSlices of IE, but can't find that one right now.

Comment: I'd say an add-on would only have to look for anchors and id's...?

Comment: SiteSlicer looks interesting but seems to support older versions of FF. Thanks for the suggestion though.   Agree with @Arjan van Bentem that it only needs to look for anchors and ids.

Answer (score 0):

This is built into Firefox (at least version 3.6, but I think all of 3.x). Click/drag to select the section of the page you're interested in, then right-click and choose "View Selection Source". I do this all the time for exactly the same reason as you. I find that anchor name tags tend to be around section headers, so usually just selecting from a few lines before to a few lines after will show me the anchor I'm interested in.